# Problems reading bigquery google sheets federated data sources into cloud datalab via pandas_gbq

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487101/bigquery-credential-problems-when-accessing-google-sheets-federated-table) -- I have basically the same question, and one of the commenters there said he had solved it but didn't flesh out the solution.

- I have data in a google sheet, which I have set up as a google BigQuery federated data source (external data source).
- I want to import this data in cloud datalab using pandas_gbq
- When I import usual (non-federated) BigQuery tables, from the same project, in the datalab instance it all works fine.
- When I try import the federated source (from the google sheet) I get the error: "GenericGBQException: Reason: accessDenied, Message: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found."

I have tried to follow mattm's instructions on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487101/bigquery-credential-problems-when-accessing-google-sheets-federated-table) post: "I had the exact same issue and I had to enable both the Drive API for the project (in addition to BigQuery API), as well as use the BigQuery+Drive scopes. I also had to then manually permission the sheets to allow access to the ...@appspot.gserviceaccount.com account my project used to access the Google Sheets with."

- I have enabled drive API for the project.
- I added the service account that is used in the datalab instance to the sharing permissions list in the google sheet: xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
- I am not sure how to "use the BigQuery+Drive scopes" ?

Has anyone else managed to get this working? Is it a matter of using BigQuery and Drive scopes, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

When formatting your request, make sure credentials have the following two scopes:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
and
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'

Comment: I found that the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly' scope on its own was sufficient. Granting cloud-platform also triggers some scary looking emails to be sent.

Comment: Where exactly do you add the scope? 
I'm using the python BigQuery api (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#bigquery-simple-app-query-python)