# Tableau Bigquery access issue with Google Sheet federated table

Tags: authentication, google-sheets, google-bigquery, tableau-api, federated

I have a View (Table A) in Big Query which was created from a Google Sheet. It updates live which is perfect.

I have then connected that View to another View (Table B) in Bigquery. Let’s call this combined View, Table C.

In Tableau Desktop I try to connect to Table C, but it comes up with an authentication issue because Tableau cannot pass on authentication to Google Sheets.

Has anyone found a solution or workaround? Using service accounts, or even cloud functions or a scheduled query which saves the results of Table A as a table every time the google sheet is saved.

This has been asked before in the following link, but hasn’t received a step-by-step solution and I do not have enough stackoverflow reputation to comment:

[BigQuery Credential Problems when Accessing Google Sheets Federated Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487101/bigquery-credential-problems-when-accessing-google-sheets-federated-table)

https://community.tableau.com/thread/207871