# bq cmd query Google Sheet Table occur "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found" Error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a table connect with Google Sheet, use WebUI query this table success, but if I use bq cmd query, It will echo error msg:

> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive
>   scope was found

Comment: just do a little search here in SO - there are quite a number of exact same questions!! have you tried?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes, I try to search, and add  --enable-gdrive-access into gcloud login, but it doesn't work, so I come to SO ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume you are using `bq` command line tool which comes with [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

To use `bq` you had to procure credentials, most likely you used

```
gcloud auth login
```

By default these credentials do not get drive scope. You have to explicitly request it via

```
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```

Now running `bq` to access Google Drive data should work.

---

From the comments: for some people, it seems to be necessary to run

```
gcloud auth revoke
```

before logging in again. (Deleting `~/.config/gcloud` would also work, but is probably overkill.)

Comment: thanks! But I try this way and It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, I know what happen, before gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access, I need delete ~/.config/gcloud folder, thanks!!

Comment: Unless you have corrupted your gcloud configuration this step of deleting the folder should not be necessary. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: how to enable drive access for service account?

Comment: @MLK, it depends on your circumstances, what type of application and where you trying to use service account. See some info https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount. If you still have questions it would warrant a separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: I also needed to delete `~/.config/gcloud` and then re-run for this to work properly.

Comment: @MLK Assuming the service account is attached to a GCE instance, than you can do this locally and then restart your instance:   ```gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes [INSTANCE_NAME] \ 
     --service-account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL] \ 
     --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive ```

Comment: @cherba I tried this and also had to remove the directory before it would work, pretty sure I haven't corrupted the directory. Seems pretty common for other people too. It would be preferable not to remove the directory but not sure what part of it is missing the `OAuth token with Google Drive scope`

Comment: It seems necessary to first execute `gcloud auth revoke` and then `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access`

Comment: I had to delete the `.config/gcloud` folder, then `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access --update-adc`  - without the last flag for some reason the `application_default_credentials.json` file wasn't appearing..

Answer (score 4):

Chances are the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly' scope is missing in the credentials of your request.

For details, see:
[Credentials Error when integrating Google Drive with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381286/credentials-error-when-integrating-google-drive-with)

Answer (score 1):

Run `auth revoke` then `auth login` if only the latter doesn't work.

```
gcloud auth revoke
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, I know what happen, before gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access, I need delete ~/.config/gcloud folder, thanks!! – Karl Lin Sep 14 '17 at 12:32

Here's the complete answer based on Karl Lin's comment to the accepted answer.

```
rm -rf ~/.config/gcloud 
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```

I needed to delete `~/.config/gcloud` or it won't work.